# Moving Swapfile in Mac OS X Lion

Tags: macos, partitioning, osx-lion, swap

I had previously consulted this thread when using snow leopard to move all swap to an SSD:

[Moving the swapfiles to a dedicated partition in Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/28414/moving-the-swapfiles-to-a-dedicated-partition-in-snow-leopard)

The information appears to be out of date at this point, and replies have been restricted (so the thread can no longer be properly updated).

How would one do this at this point?

Answer (score 1):

The essence of the question to which you refer is now in Ask Different:

#### [How can I move virtual memory swap files to a different drive or partition?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/1465/8546)

The [accepted answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/1469/8546) should be good for both **Lion** and Mountain Lion. I made a Lion-oriented edition.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an app called [Xupport](http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/9256/xupport) from Applicorn should do this.

However, the rest of their site, including the download, appears to be down now.

Comment: Xsupport is listed as not Lion compatible at http://roaringapps.com/app:2182 "Won't open at all on Lion".

Comment: That link seems to be offline now as well. It's giving me a big 'ol 404.

Comment: I have tried the instructions listed for Snow Leopard, and they still work for Lion.