# Can't move OS X swap file to another folder, it keeps being recreated

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, swap

So I followed these instructions to the letter ---> [Moving the swapfiles to a dedicated partition in Snow Leopard](https://superuser.com/questions/28414/moving-the-swapfiles-to-a-dedicated-partition-in-snow-leopard)

But for some reason, the swap files keep being regenerated in the same folder.
I've checked everything that I can think of.

Here's a screen shot of my configuration in nano,

[image]

- I have a volume named swap and a .vm folder inside of it,
- I've used command+v to do a verbose boot, no problems there
- I've looked in the console and there is no mention of dynamic_loader
- there is no 'swap' symbolic link in my volumes folder that might confuse my actual 'swap' partition into being incorrectly named

It seems like the file is simply being ignored and I can't figure out why. I'm at my wits end, just wanted to know if there was a fresh pair of eyes could spot something I missed or suggest something else to try.